# Initial run blocks UI due to DLLs lazy loading (asynchronous)

Tags: wpf, reactiveui, .net-core-3.1

**Updated question:**

I'm having a long running `async` method, I've built a WPF GUI to execute it. GUI is using `ReactiveUI`. I need to have some UI Feedback for users when the `async` process is running. The **first click** on the button always hangs the GUI. I've noticed in the Output window of Visual Studio when I ran my application in Debug mode:: the first time when the button was clicked, clrhost loaded a lot of DLLs (`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.xxx.dll`, `Microsoft.Extensions.[Caching/DependencyInjection/...].xxx.dll` ...) and that seemed to be the culprit which made the GUI looked like it was hang for a couple seconds.

Looks like the DLLs were only loaded when required for the first time the library was called. Is there anyway to give GUI the feedback before those DLLs loaded?

---

**Original question:**

I'm pretty new to ReactiveUI. I'm creating an UI when user click a button, it will execute a long running asynchronous command. I want to provide some feedback on the GUI when the process starts and finishes.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32987345/proper-way-to-provide-feedback-from-long-running-command-using-reactiveui-in-wpf) mentioned `Subject`, so this is what I came up with:

ViewModel:

```cs
public class MainWindowVM : ReactiveObject
{
    public enum ProcessStatus
    {
        Running,
        Completed,
        Error
    }

    private readonly ReplaySubject<ProcessStatus> _exportCSVCommandReplayStatus;
    public readonly ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> ExportDatabaseToCSV;

    private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<string> _csvExportMessage;
    public string CSVExportMessage => _csvExportMessage.Value;

    private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<ProcessStatus> _exportDatabaseToCSVStatus;
    public ProcessStatus ExportDatabaseToCSVStatus => _exportDatabaseToCSVStatus.Value;

    public MainWindowVM()
    {
        _exportCSVCommandReplayStatus = new ReplaySubject<ProcessStatus>(1);

        _exportDatabaseToCSVStatus = _exportCSVCommandReplayStatus
            .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
            .ToProperty(this, nameof(ExportDatabaseToCSVStatus), ProcessStatus.Completed);

        ExportDatabaseToCSV = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(ExportDatabaseToCSVAsync, canExecute:
            this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.ExportDatabaseToCSVStatus, status => status != ProcessStatus.Running));

        // error handlers
        ExportDatabaseToCSV.ThrownExceptions.Subscribe(ex => {
            _exportCSVCommandReplayStatus.OnNext(ProcessStatus.Error);
            //ErrorHandler(ex);
        });

        _exportCSVCommandReplayStatus
            .Select(status => status switch
            {
                ProcessStatus.Running => "CSV exporting...",
                ProcessStatus.Error => "CSV export error! Check log for more details",
                ProcessStatus.Completed => "CSV export completed.",
                _ => ""
            })
            .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
            .ToProperty(this, x => x.CSVExportMessage, out _csvExportMessage);
    }

    private async Task ExportDatabaseToCSVAsync()
    {
        _exportCSVCommandReplayStatus.OnNext(ProcessStatus.Running);
        
        await Util.ExportDBToCSV();

        _exportCSVCommandReplayStatus.OnNext(ProcessStatus.Completed);
    }
}
```

And then make all the bindings accordingly in the View. Simple demonstration: a button, a progress bar, and a label

```cs
...
    this.BindCommand(ViewModel,
            vm => vm.ExportDatabaseToCSV,
            v => v.BtnExportDatabaseCSV)
        .DisposeWith(d);

     this.OneWayBind(ViewModel,
            vm => vm.ExportDatabaseToCSVStatus,
            v => v.PrgBarCSVExporting.Visibility,
            status => status == ProcessStatus.Running
                ? Visibility.Visible
                : Visibility.Collapsed)
        .DisposeWith(d);

    this.OneWayBind(ViewModel,
            vm => vm.CSVExportMessage,
            v => v.LblCSVExportingStatusMessage.Content)
        .DisposeWith(d);
...
```

The problem I ran into was: when the button was clicked for the **first time**, the **UI was blocked**, and completed message displayed suddenly after a while.

All the subsequence clicks work as expected (i.e. button is disabled, progress bar showing, message update...)

Am I doing it wrongly? What is the recommended way to deal with this scenario in ReactiveUI?

Subscribing to `IsExecuting` of the `ReactiveCommand` produced the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an output property to indicate the command is running and read-write property to set the current status based on the current state of the view model:

```
public class MainWindowVM : ReactiveObject
{
    public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> ExportDatabaseToCSV { get; }

    private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<bool> _isRunning;
    public bool IsRunning => _isRunning.Value;

    private ProcessStatus _status;
    public ProcessStatus Status
    {
        get => _status;
        private set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _status, value);
    }

    public MainWindowVM()
    {
        ExportDatabaseToCSV = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(ExportDatabaseToCSVAsync);
        ExportDatabaseToCSV.IsExecuting.ToProperty(this, x => x.IsRunning, out _isRunning);
        this.ObservableForProperty(x => x.IsRunning).Where(_ => IsRunning).Subscribe(_ => Status = ProcessStatus.Running);
        ExportDatabaseToCSV.ThrownExceptions.Subscribe(_ => Status = ProcessStatus.Error);
        ExportDatabaseToCSV.Subscribe(_ => Status = ProcessStatus.Completed);
    }

    private async Task ExportDatabaseToCSVAsync()
    {
        await ...
    }
}

public enum ProcessStatus
{
    Default,
    Running,
    Completed,
    Error
}
```

**View:**

```
this.WhenActivated(d =>
{
    this.BindCommand(ViewModel,
        vm => vm.ExportDatabaseToCSV,
        v => v.BtnExportDatabaseCSV)
            .DisposeWith(d);

    this.OneWayBind(ViewModel,
                    vm => vm.IsRunning,
                    v => v.PrgBarCSVExporting.Visibility)
                    .DisposeWith(d);

    this.OneWayBind(ViewModel,
        vm => vm.Status,
        v => v.LblCSVExportingStatusMessage.Content)
        .DisposeWith(d);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I have actually used this approach for other GUI which just showed 2 status `executing` and `stopped`. The reason I'm going with a `ReplaySubject` was to potentially report different status, percentage progressing... etc

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and behaviour was still the same. I've updated my question

Comment: @Mr.DucNguyen: My code does not block the UI assuming the implementation of `ExportDatabaseToCSVAsync` is truly async and non-blocking. Try to replace "..." with `await Task.Delay(5000)` for example.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have updated my question. The real problem was probably because of lazy loading of DLLs. That explained why it happened only on the **first click**. Any chance you had the same problem before?

Comment: @Mr.DucNguyen: No, I certainly haven't.